# How to get data from DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json.net

I send POST data to server and get response in json and then I use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` but I don`t know how I can get data from this?

I tried make my own Minecraft Launcher but I'm stuck in this moment :/

https://wiki.vg/Authentication#Response

```cs
public class SelectedProfile
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public SelectedProfile SelectedProfile { get; set; }
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public string ClientToken { get; set; }
}

public static void ObtainAccessToken(string username, string password)
{
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = "{\"agent\":{\"name\":\"Minecraft\",\"version\":1},\"username\":\"" + username + "\",\"password\":\"" + password + "\"}";

        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(result);

            SelectedProfile u = new SelectedProfile();
            MainWindow f2 = new MainWindow();

            MessageBox.Show(u.Id + Environment.NewLine + account.AccessToken + Environment.NewLine + account.ClientToken);

            f2.richTextBox1.Text = u.Id;
            f2.richTextBox1.Text = account.AccessToken;
            f2.richTextBox1.Text = account.ClientToken;
            f2.richTextBox1.Text = u.Name;

            f2.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

account.AccessToken and account.ClientToken works fine but Id and Name doesn't

Comment: You aren't populating `u` with any data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a `new SelectedProfile()`, so how you expect to see any values there ?
You need to use `account.SelectedProfile`, because you're passing the json string to `DeserializeObject` method and getting the result in the `account` object.